# Git hangs with a ssh remote URI after 10.15.4 update

Tags: catalina, ssh, git

After updating to Catalina 10.15.4, `git` started hanging indefinitely when trying to push or pull from a repo that was previously accessible.

```
$ git push origin master
^C
```

The URL for `origin` looks like:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:30814/username/project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:30814/username/project.git (push)
```

Attempting to ssh directly to the remote results in a hang:

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh -p 30814 git@gitlab.example.com -vvv
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.example.com port 30814.
^C
```

Which seems to indicate the underlying problem with `git` is the `ssh://` URI for the remote repository. I confirmed this by successfully cloning the repo using a `https://` URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging steps:

1. Attempted to connect with netcat:

```
$ nc -v gitlab.example.com 30814
Connection to gitlab.example.com port 30814 [tcp/*] succeeded!
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
^C
```

2. Suspecting a broken ssh client, I installed openssh using brew:

```
$ brew install openssh
...
$ /usr/local/bin/ssh  -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

$ /usr/local/bin/ssh -p 30814 git@gitlab.example.com
Welcome to GitLab, @username!
Connection to gitlab.example.com closed.
```

After refreshing my shell environment to ensure that the new ssh is found in my `$PATH`, git operations began functioning as expected with `ssh://` URIs.

Searching turned up this user submitted bug: [ssh fails when using -p flag](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB7641404)

The workaround detailed in the bug is to use the remote host's IP address instead of the DNS name. I can confirm that this worked for me:

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

$ /usr/bin/ssh -p 30814 git@192.168.1.1
Welcome to GitLab, @username!
Connection to gitlab.example.com closed.
```

The apparent trigger for this bug is using ports greater than 8192 in conjunction with a host's DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

This one fixed it for me:

```
brew uninstall openssl --ignore-dependencies; brew uninstall openssl --ignore-dependencies; brew uninstall libressl --ignore-dependencies; brew install openssh;
```

results in

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g
```

being used by ssh ...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I ran into this issue with Monterey 12.7.2.

I regenerated ssh keys (not sure if this was the critical bit) and changed
`~/.ssh/config` to have

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  UseKeychain no
```

Hope this saves someone some time.